# getting null while using google calendar api in php

Tags: php, calendar

I want to receive list of all Google calendars.Am using google calendar api but it gives empty in items.Here is my code that i use:

```
  $client_id='#######.apps.googleusercontent.com';
 $service_account_name = '#####';
 $calName = 'jkl@gmail.com';
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setApplicationName("#####");
 $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
 $client->setAuthConfig('###########');
 putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=##########');
 $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

 //for getting all calendars
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
print_r($calendarList);
while(true) {
foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
 }
$pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
if ($pageToken) {
$optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
 } else {
break;
  }
}
```

and the output that i receive :

```
Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList Object ( [collection_key:protected]   => items [etag] => "p32off2tdka0d40g"       [itemsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry [itemsDataType:protected] => array [kind] => calendar#calendarList [nextPageToken] => [nextSyncToken] => CLD3i62igNICEil4cGVydGVjaEBuZXcteHBlci5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbQ== [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [modelData:protected] => Array ( [items] => Array ( ) ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: never ever provide your details in question.People can use it in bad manner. Be careful.Remove credentials asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem actually i am missing one step that is share the calendar with service account email.